# Facebook Login not working through app

Tags: java, android, facebook

I've got a problem logging in with facebook on my app.
Logging in only works when the Android Facebook app is not installed. In that case you'll get a popup from facebook. 
When the Facebook app is installed, the login will redirect to the app. In this case I don't get my session token back, instead I get the message: CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED

I've been looking all over the place, but I really can't find the problem.

This is the code in my Fragment, The login button is created through XML:

```
private void initButtons()
    {
            btnFacebook.setApplicationId(v.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.app_id));
            btnFacebook.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile", "user_birthday"));
            btnFacebook.setFragment(this);
            btnFacebook.setSessionStatusCallback(new StatusCallback()
            {

              @Override
              public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception)
              {
                Log.d("Token:",session.getAccessToken());
              }

            });
    }

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this.getActivity(), requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

Any ideas what I might be missing? Again, the login only works without the facebook app installed

EDIT:
I get a Session Closed Login Failed message when the account which is used, already registered the app. When user first logs in using this app (added to their account) the results are as they should be

Answer (score 0):

Use the below given class as a Facebook helper that might deal with you error.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookOperationCanceledException;
import com.facebook.FacebookServiceException;
import com.facebook.HttpMethod;
import com.facebook.LoggingBehavior;
import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.RequestAsyncTask;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.Settings;
import com.facebook.widget.WebDialog;
import com.quickblox.q_municate.R;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

public class FacebookHelper {

    public static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions", "publish_stream");
    private Activity activity;
    private Session.StatusCallback facebookStatusCallback;
    private Resources resources;

    public FacebookHelper(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState,
            Session.StatusCallback facebookStatusCallback) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.facebookStatusCallback = facebookStatusCallback;
        resources = activity.getResources();
        initFacebook(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public static void logout() {
        if (Session.getActiveSession() != null) {
            Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();
        }
    }

    private void initFacebook(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null) {
            return;
        }
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            session = Session.restoreSession(activity, null, facebookStatusCallback, savedInstanceState);
        }
        if (session == null) {
            session = new Session(activity);
        }
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(activity).setCallback(facebookStatusCallback));
        }
    }

    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        Session.saveSession(session, outState);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(activity, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    public void loginWithFacebook() {
        TipsManager.setIsJustLogined(true);
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(activity).setCallback(facebookStatusCallback));
        } else {
            Session.openActiveSession(activity, true, facebookStatusCallback);
        }
    }

    public void onActivityStart() {
        Session.getActiveSession().addCallback(facebookStatusCallback);
    }

    public void onActivityStop() {
        if (Session.getActiveSession() != null) {
            Session.getActiveSession().removeCallback(facebookStatusCallback);
        }
    }

    public boolean isSessionOpened() {
        return Session.getActiveSession().isOpened();
    }

    public void postInviteToWall(Request.Callback requestCallback, String[] selectedFriends) {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null) {
            Resources resources = activity.getResources();
            Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
            //Data from string.xml to post on wall ...You have to include the permission for posting
            postParams.putString(Consts.FB_WALL_PARAM_NAME, resources.getString(R.string.inf_fb_wall_param_name));
            postParams.putString(Consts.FB_WALL_PARAM_DESCRIPTION, resources.getString(R.string.inf_fb_wall_param_description));
            postParams.putString(Consts.FB_WALL_PARAM_LINK, resources.getString(R.string.inf_fb_wall_param_link));
            postParams.putString(Consts.FB_WALL_PARAM_PICTURE, resources.getString(R.string.inf_fb_wall_param_picture));
            postParams.putString(Consts.FB_WALL_PARAM_PLACE, resources.getString(R.string.inf_fb_wall_param_place));
            postParams.putString(Consts.FB_WALL_PARAM_TAGS, TextUtils.join(",", selectedFriends));
            Request request = new Request(session, Consts.FB_WALL_PARAM_FEED, postParams, HttpMethod.POST, requestCallback);
            RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
            task.execute();
        }
    }

    private Bundle getBundleForFriendsRequest() {
        Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
        postParams.putString(Consts.FB_REQUEST_PARAM_TITLE, resources.getString(R.string.inf_subject_of_invitation));
        postParams.putString(Consts.FB_REQUEST_PARAM_MESSAGE, resources.getString(R.string.inf_body_of_invitation));
        return postParams;
    }

    public WebDialog getWebDialogRequest() {
        Bundle postParams = getBundleForFriendsRequest();
        return (new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(activity,
                Session.getActiveSession(), postParams)).setOnCompleteListener(
                getWebDialogOnCompleteListener()).build();
    }

    private WebDialog.OnCompleteListener getWebDialogOnCompleteListener() {
        return new WebDialog.OnCompleteListener() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values, FacebookException facebookException) {
                parseFacebookRequestError(values, facebookException);
            }
        };
    }

    private void parseFacebookRequestError(Bundle values, FacebookException facebookException) {
        if (facebookException != null) {
            if (facebookException instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                DialogUtils.showLong(activity, resources.getString(R.string.inf_fb_request_canceled));
            } else if (facebookException instanceof FacebookServiceException) {
                final int errorCodeCancel = 4201;
                FacebookServiceException facebookServiceException = (FacebookServiceException) facebookException;
                if (errorCodeCancel == facebookServiceException.getRequestError().getErrorCode()) {
                    DialogUtils.showLong(activity, resources.getString(R.string.inf_fb_request_canceled));
                } else {
                    ErrorUtils.showError(activity,
                            facebookServiceException.getRequestError().getErrorMessage());
                }
            } else if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(facebookException.getMessage())) {
                ErrorUtils.showError(activity, facebookException);
            }
        } else {
            final String requestId = values.getString("request");
            if (requestId != null) {
                DialogUtils.showLong(activity, resources.getString(R.string.dlg_success_request_facebook));
            } else {
                DialogUtils.showLong(activity, resources.getString(R.string.inf_fb_request_canceled));
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean checkPermissions() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
        if (!isSubsetOf(FacebookHelper.PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(activity,
                    FacebookHelper.PERMISSIONS);
            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset) {
        for (String string : subset) {
            if (!superset.contains(string)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

You can also get this class from the gist link https://gist.github.com/LPURockers/e9cba51d85ffdf077062

Comment: It didn't work. The weird part is, that the app closes immediately after pressing the login button, it doesn't even show the permissions that are required. When not using the facebook app for login, the persmissions are shown

Comment: I think you might have missed something, for help you can take assistance from Qmunicate App. https://github.com/QuickBlox/q-municate-android/blob/master/Q-municate/src/main/java/com/quickblox/q_municate/ui/authorization/base/BaseAuthActivity.java

Comment: I have created another app on the facebook console, and there it is able to log in. I have been changing settings on the dashboard, but I can't seem to reproduce the error. The only thing I changed in the code is the app id. And they are both correct

Comment: Well it's not the correct answer I need to be able to log in to the original app on Facebook. There is an iOS app connected to it already with a lot of users. So I really need to fix the error on it

Comment: Try the above comment link to add facebook login in your app. That might help you.